# Is there a way to let ttk widget accept variable with $ sign?

Tags: variables, tcl, ttk

letś say i have a ttk radiobutton , i would like to be able to use it like

```
ttk::radiobutton .a$b -text -variable a$b
```

but only the command path ".a$b" works as expected, the variable part "a$b" does not work.

is there a way to make this work?

below is a sample demonstrating the problem:

```
[lzhou@promote tcl]$ tclsh
% set a 1
1
% set b 0
0
% puts $a$b
10
% set a0 100
100
% puts a$b
a0
% puts ${a$b}
can't read "a$b": no such variable
```

Comment: Why does that not work? If you do `set b 1`, and then execute the radiobutton command (of course, after supplying a text, which is not present in your current command), then the variable name will be `a1`. What is your expectation and what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: another related question is how do you get the value of "a$b" ?  {$a$b}  will give you "$a" and "$b" concatenated together , but not ${a$b} which is what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call “works” but you have a variable whose name is partially variable. Usually when you're doing that, the easiest way forward is to use an *array variable* instead.

```
ttk::radiobutton .a$b -text -variable a($b)
# Note the (parentheses) above!
```

```
puts $a($b)
```

---

### Other less-recommended alternatives

If not that, then the best techniques for reading from the variable either use the single-argument form of `set` (which actually predates the `$` syntax):

```
puts [set a$b]
```

or to make an alias to the variable with a fixed name, using `upvar 0`:

```
upvar 0 a$b theVarAlias
puts $theVarAlias
```

If you're doing many manipulations on the variable, the second option is superior as aliases are more efficient than looking up a variable name over and over. They do have a little more overhead though so they're not so fast for a one-off use.

*We do not recommend reading variables with computed expressions or other weird incantations of `expr` or `subst`.* Those are too tricky in practice. Too many weird edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

O.K. I find an answer:

```
% expr [join [concat "$" "a" $b] "" ]
100
```